# Run maven command on prod using jar

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I have a jhipster project which i am deploying on prod using the command

`java -jar project.jar`

but during development I renamed some columns in some tables, when I am redeploying the code I am getting error of liquibase, I am told if I run the command below it should fix.

`./mvnw liquibase:changelogsync`

I do not have the code on prod but only jar file, please advise , what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: You should never change existing changelogs that have been run in production as they are supposed to be immutable, only add new changelogs. So, I would recommend you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should spend a little time with the jHipster or Liquibase documentation to understand what it is doing. You didn't mention what the error was, but I am guessing it was probably something like "checksum for changeset with id xxxx changed from yyyy to zzzz." If you were able to run changelogsync in production, it would just mark all the changesets in your changelog as run by updating the checksum in the databasechangelog table on production, but your database tables will not have the correct columns.

Presumably you have run things in production and you have a table with some column - lets pretend it is named A for example. You say you renamed the column, lets pretend the new name is B. If you did that change by just changing the create table statement in the changelog, then if you run changelogsync in production what happens is that liquibase would think that the changeset to create the table and the column with name B has been run, but in fact it has not been run.

Instead, revert the changelog to what it was before, and rather than renaming the column by changing the changeset, create a new changeset that uses [the liquibase renameColumn change type](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/rename_column.html) to rename the column.